# Removing cursor t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have a trigger in mssql in which I want to compare each column from the inserted table with the deleted table to check if the value has changed...
If the value has changed I want to insert the column name into a temp table.

My code until now:

```
declare columnCursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo'

--save inserted and deleted into temp tables
select * into #row1 from Inserted
select * into #row2 from Deleted

declare @tmp table(column_name nvarchar(max))
declare @column nvarchar(50)

OPEN COlumnCUrsor
FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnCursor INTO @column
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0 begin

    declare @out bit
    declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
      select @out = case when r1.'+@column+'r2.'+@column+' then 1 else 0 end 
      from #row1 r1 
      left join #row2 r2 on r1.sys_volgnr=r2.sys_volgnr'

    exec sp_executesql @sql,N'@out bit OUTPUT', @out=@out OUTPUT

    if( @out = 1 ) begin
        insert into @tmp VALUES(@column)
    end

    FETCH NEXT FROM ColumnCursor INTO @column
end

CLOSE ColumnCursor;
DEALLOCATE ColumnCursor;
```

Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: Bad assumption ahoy! `inserted` and `deleted` can contain *multiple* rows (or no rows). Also, although you've not written it correctly yet, a naive comparison within your `CASE` expression between two columns will ignore `NULL`s, which probably isn't desirable.

Comment: And for heaven's sake don't copy inserted and deleted into temp tables. They already exist, there is no need to make a copy of them.

Comment: @SeanLange - there is a need if you want another scope to have access to them (such as a stored proc, or, as here, dynamic SQL) since they're only accessible within the scope of the trigger itself. Not that I'd recommend using code such as in the OP, but there can be occasions where the copy is needed.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have never even considered such a crazy thing. If I were in that situation I would work hard to find a different alternative than copying the inserted and deleted tables. And from what we see posted there really doesn't appear to be any reason to need dynamic sql, but that could be to simplify for posting.

Comment: In my case its not a bad assumption because I know for sure there is only 1 row in the inserted table.. the case expression is not correct indeed but it's only for explaining the code..  Furthermore I need to copy the tables into temp tables because it's another scope when you run dynamic sql as @Damien_The_Unbeliever points out correctly. I tried a lot of ways but the only way i could get to work is the statement above.. but I almost know for sure that i could lose the cursor by writing this query in a different way.. but what way?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is.
You can use the [`COLUMNS_UPDATED`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/columns-updated-transact-sql?view=sqlallproducts-allversions) function to determine the columns that had actually changed values, though it's not a very friendly function in terms of code readability.
Read [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/232195) from Microsoft support called Proper Use of the COLUMNS_UPDATED() Function to see what I mean.

I've came across an article called [A More Performant Alternative To COLUMNS_UPDATED()](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wardpond/archive/2006/02/16/database-programming-a-more-performant-alternative-to-columns-updated.aspx), perhaps it can help you or at least inspire you.

I will note that you should resist the temptation to use the [`UPDATE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx) function, as it may return true even if no data was changed.
here is the relevant part from it's MSDN page:

> UPDATE() returns TRUE regardless of whether an INSERT or UPDATE attempt is successful.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.. My first approach was with this columns_updated function. But in my case it's not usable.. all columns in the row are updated because the underlying code (which is not in my hands) controls it this way..

Comment: If all the column are updated then what's the point of you test anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to build a dynamic solution, which might be useful if you expect to change often (=new columns to be added etc). You could do something like this (in pseudo-code)

Build a dynamic SQL based on DMVs (INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS) for the column names:

```
insert into table ...
select
  function_to_split_by_comma (
  case when I.col1 = U.col1 then 'col1,' else '' end +
  case when I.col2 = U.col2 then 'col2,' else '' end +
  ...
  )
where
 I.key_column1 = U.key_column1 ...
```

These names (col1, col2) should be the columns from the DMV query, + the case for each of the row, and then fixed SQL part for the beginning + you'll need to figure out how to join inserted and deleted, which requires the primary key.

For splitting the data into rows, you can use for example the delimited_split_8k by Jeff Moden (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/).

Also as Damien pointed out, there can be more than one row in the inserted / deleted tables.

Comment: I wouldn't really recommend this for table that has a lot of updates, since this can cause performance issues.